# SF2.8 Undefined index: FormType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am junior and working with Symfony 2.8 on a project.
I have this error when trying to reach a complicated edit form that I absolutely don't understand :

> Notice: Undefined index: \TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType
>
> Stack Trace :
>
> 1. in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php at
>      line 103
>
> @trigger_error(sprintf('Accessing type "%s" by its string name is
>   deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   fully-qualified type class name "%s" instead.', $name,
>   get_class($this->types[$name]->getInnerType())), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
>           }
>           return $this->types[$name];
>       }
>       /**
>
> 2. at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('8', 'Undefined index: \TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType',
>      'C:\xampp\htdocs\tkstrs\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php',
>      '103', array('name' => '\TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType', 'type'
>      => object(ArticleEditType), 'extension' => object(DependencyInjectionExtension)))  in
>      vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php at
>      line 103 (...)

**My edit form :**

```
<?php

namespace TKS\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use TKS\BlogBundle\Form\VilleContributionType;

class ArticleEditType extends AbstractType {


/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $this->idarticle = $options['idarticle'];
    $idarticle = $this->idarticle;


    $builder
            ->add('titre', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Titre',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('legende', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Légende',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('texte', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => ' ',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('source', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => ' ',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('lieu', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom du lieu',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('adresse', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Adresse',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
            ->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'TKSBlogBundle:Ville',
                'expanded' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une ville',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'multiple' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->orderBy('v.ville', 'ASC');
                },
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form'),
                'label' => 'Ville',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('villeContribution', VilleContributionType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => ' '
            ))
            ->add('tags', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'TKSBlogBundle:Tag',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->orderBy('t.nameFR', 'ASC');
                },
                'attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'label' => 'Tags',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('tagsFree', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'TKSBlogBundle:TagFree',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($idarticle) {
                    return $er->findTagsFreeByArticle($idarticle);
                },
                'attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'label' => ' ',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('tagsFreeNew', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Nouveau tag',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control widget-form')
            ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'TKS\BlogBundle\Entity\Article',
        'idarticle' => null
    ));
}
}
```

**My Controller :**

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Article entity.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/editorial/{id}/edit", name="article_edit_editorial")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editEditorialAction(Request $request, Article $article) {
    $idarticle = $article->getId();
    $editForm = $this->createForm('\TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType', $article, array('idarticle' => $idarticle));

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    // récupération de la liste des tags
    $tagsList = $editForm->get('tagsFreeNew')->getData();
    if ($tagsList != null) {
        // convertion de la liste en tableau
        $tagsArray = explode(',', $tagsList);
        $tagsArray = array_unique($tagsArray); // supprime les doublons dans un tableau
    }

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($tagsList != null) {
            // on boucle sur le tableau de tags
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($tagsArray); $i++) {
                $tagName = $tagsArray[$i];
                $tagName = trim($tagName);

                // on vérifie l'existence du tag. Si oui->récupération...
                $tagFreeEntity = $em->getRepository('TKSBlogBundle:TagFree')->findOneByName($tagName);
                $tagEntity = $em->getRepository('TKSBlogBundle:Tag')->findOneByNameFR($tagName);


                // si non, instanciation
                if ($tagFreeEntity == null && $tagEntity == null) {
                    $tagFreeEntity = new \TKS\BlogBundle\Entity\TagFree();
                    $tagFreeEntity->setName($tagName);
                    // on ajoute le tag à l'article
                    $article->addTagsFree($tagFreeEntity);
                }

                // si tag déjà existant mais pas présent dans l'article , ajout du tag à l'article
                if ($tagFreeEntity == null && $tagEntity != null) {

                    if (!in_array($tagEntity, $article->getTags())) {
                        // on ajoute le tag à l'article
                        $article->addTag($tagEntity);
                    }
                }

                // si tagFree déjà existant mais pas présent dans l'article, ajout du tagFree à l'article
                if ($tagFreeEntity != null) {

                    if ($tagFreeEntity == $article->getTagsFree()) {
                        $article->addTagsFree($tagFreeEntity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // on enregistre le pays
        if ($article->getVille() != null) {
            $article->setPays($article->getVille()->getPays());
        } else if ($article->getVilleContribution() != null) {
            $article->setPays($article->getVilleContribution()->getPays());
        }


        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        // flashbag en cas de succès
        $this->addFlash('success', 'L\'enregistrement a été effectué avec succès !');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_index_editorial');
    }

    return $this->render('TKSBlogBundle:Article:editEditorial.html.twig', array(
                'article' => $article,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**My view :**

```
    {% extends 'TKSBlogBundle:Article:indexEditorial.html.twig' %}

{% block tab %}
    <h3 class="title">Modifier l'article &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{{ path('article_index_editorial') }}" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-sm">Annuler</a></h3>
    <hr>    
    {% form_theme edit_form '::baseform.html.twig' %}
    {{ form_start(edit_form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal' } } ) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.titre) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.titre) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.titre) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.legende) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.legende) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.legende) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            <a class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTexte" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseContent">Ajouter un texte <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse " id="collapseTexte" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
                {{ form_label(edit_form.texte) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
                {{ form_widget(edit_form.texte) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.texte) }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            <a class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSource" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseContent">Ajouter une source <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse " id="collapseSource" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
                {{ form_label(edit_form.source) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
                {{ form_widget(edit_form.source) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.source) }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.lieu) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.lieu) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.lieu) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.adresse) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.adresse) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.adresse) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.ville) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.ville) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.ville) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            La ville que vous cherchez n'apparaît pas dans la liste ?
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseVille2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseContent">Proposer une nouvelle ville <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse " id="collapseVille2" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
                {{ form_label(edit_form.villeContribution) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
                {{ form_widget(edit_form.villeContribution) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.villeContribution) }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    {# TAGS #}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
            {{ form_label(edit_form.tags) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.tags) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.tags) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
            <a class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTagsFree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseContent">Ajouter un tag personnel <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse " id="collapseTagsFree" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
                {{ form_label(edit_form.tagsFree) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
                {{ form_widget(edit_form.tagsFree) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.tagsFree) }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10 control-label label-form">
                {{ form_label(edit_form.tagsFreeNew) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 ">
                {{ form_widget(edit_form.tagsFreeNew) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(edit_form.tagsFreeNew) }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="label-form text-center">
        <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Enregistrer et continuer</button>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(edit_form) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <!-- javascript pour formulaires imbriqués Tags -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            $("input[type='checkbox']").before("<br>");
            $("div#article_tags").addClass("checkbox");

        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea that could help me please ?

Comment: Can you try to replace `$editForm = $this->createForm('\TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType', $article, array('idarticle' => $idarticle));` by `$editForm = $this->createForm('TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType', $article, array('idarticle' => $idarticle));` please? (Removed trailing backslash, not sure it's the real problem though)

Comment: OMG ! it worked ! I didn't believe in it at all... Thank you so much !!

Comment: Actually, I now understand that they also tell me to use the new way of writing it in expectation of v3.0 : TKS\BlogBundle\Form\ArticleEditType::class